# database connection error during second attempt

Tags: java, mysql

Could somebody tell me why if I try to connect to database using this code an errors occurs?

```
conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:" + this.dbms +"://" + this.serverName +":" + this.portNumber +"/" + this.dbName, connectionProps);
con.close();
conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:" + this.dbms +"://" + this.serverName +":" + this.portNumber +"/" + this.dbName, connectionProps);
```

When I type only the first line everything is ok and I can connect to the database but if I try to reconnect using all 3 lines I get an error:

```
resultset is from update. no data
```

Comment: Are you sure you get this error from the statements you showed?

Comment: Propably yes because as I said if i use only the first line I can use connection to get or put things to database. It is weird because the third line is the same as first. If there is necessity i can give more code.

Comment: What code is there between the closing of the first connection and opening of second?  Also you're closing variable `con` while opening variable `conn`.

Comment: Thats not the problem. In original code there is conn only. I can't give more code in answer because I'm a new user and i can't answer to my question now :(

Comment: You can edit your question and add more code.

Comment: I don't think you would get `resultset is from update. no data` while getting a connection. There should be some other query executing which is causing this error. `getConnection()` returns a `Connection` object, only a `SELECT` query returns a `ResultSet`

Answer (score 0):

Why you wrote same code again and again 
  try to write two functions one for connection another for disconnection call those functions
  for reconnect